# How to format columns in empty excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have a report of consisting of 20 columns in a excel sheet, where all the columns are in general format.

If i copy the report and paste to new sheet some of the columns need to be in text format.

However by selecting a columns and converting to required format is easy but how to make columns in a sheet of required type after copying from report?

Please help, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I do not believe what you seek is possible.  It is when you place a value in a cell that Excel determines the type of the value and converts it as required.  You can stop Excel performing this conversion by setting the cell to Text format **in advance**. Once the conversion has been completed you cannot later ask Excel to undo it.  How are you copying the values?

Comment: Copying directly by ctrl+c. yes Excel determines the type of the value and converts it as required, but while converting number which is in general format which has 11 or more digits it is showing exponential value and the number is storing as text.

Comment: According to my experimentation, when entering into a general format cell a number of up to 12 digits will be displayed in normal format while a number of 13 digits or more will be displayed in exponential format. A subsequent change to text format will not change the actual or display value although it is now displayed left-justified. If a number is entered into a text format cell, it remains a string of left-justified digits. Copying any of these values using Ctrl+C has no effect on the value or its appearance. Have you experienced something different? What do you want to happen?

Comment: Thanks tony for your time, Yes it is 12 digits not 11 digits. whenever converting vaules from general to number format, we have to select respected column, then by doing left indent we will get correct numerical value. but is there any way to **format empty sheet** columns as required before copying such that there is no need to format columns as required after copying.

Comment: You can select a range (such as a column) and then format every cell within it as a single operation.  `Ctrl+C` copies the format from the source to the destination cell so that would not help.  `Paste Special, Values` copies the values without the formatting.  `Paste Special, Formulas` copies the formulae but they becomes semi-strings.  The displayed value changes if you change a cell used in the formula but you cannot change the formula.  There are alternatives with VBA but you have flagged this as an Excel question so perhaps VBA is not appropriate.

Comment: I have tried formating columns in empty excel sheet and save and close. if i open the sheet, formats of columns whichever changed is in that format only, but when i try to paste whatevr format of report sheet is applying,               i have very little knowledge of vba, i'l check for solutions. i'l tag this for vba too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8997/discussion-between-expfresh-and-tony-dallimore)

Answer (score 1):

If the new report consists of all the same formatting, you could just right click on the sheet tab at the bottom, select Move or Copy, and then "create a copy" to either a new sheet or workbook. That would preserve all your formatting.

Then you could do a "paste special values" and everything should be as you would like.

> > I abbreviated the steps... I can make them more concise if this sounds like it would solve your issue.